# How do I change the views handler type for a field from string to int?

Tags: views, entities

I'm using Views 3 on Drupal 7 with the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.  My Computed Field calculates an int, and it is stored in the DB as an int, but Views is using the string handler by default.

How can I change the handler for one specific field from string to int?

This is the code I'm using in a custom module in `mymodule.views.inc`.

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  dpm($data);
  $data['user']['field_my_custom_field']['field']['handler'] = 'views_handler_field_numeric';
}
```

However, in my view, the filter choices are still:

- Is equal to
- Is not equal to
- Contains
- Contains any word
- Starts with
- etc.

These are the string options; I need them to be the choices for int (greater than, less than, etc.)

Comment: See the third example in the code in [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7), that should get you 90% of the way...

Comment: Think I see what's wrong, I've put an answer in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "should" just need to override the *filter* handler for the field, e.g.

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['user']['field_my_custom_field']['filter']['handler'] = 'views_handler_filter_numeric';
}
```

Untested, use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I ultimately solved the problem by changing the type of my Computed Field from *varchar* to *int*-- I thought I had set it as int, but I was mistaken.